# Downloaded compressed data (`gz`) from django server using ajax is inflated and broken

Tags: django, ajax

I'm trying to download a `.gz` file from a django server (Python 3.7) using Ajax post request. This is the minimal django view function and Ajax function to request download on client, compress a folder and send it (server) and receive the data on the client:

```py
from pathlib import Path 

def downloadfile(request):
    folder = Path().home().joinpath('workspace')
    tar_path =  Path().home().joinpath('workspace.gz')
    tar = tarfile.open(tar_path.as_posix(), 'w:gz')
    tar.add(folder.as_posix(), arcname='workspace')
    tar.close()

    try:
        with open(tar_path.as_posix(), 'rb') as f:
            file_data = f.read()
        response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/gzip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="workspace.gz"'
    except IOError:
        response = HttpResponse('File not exist')

    return response
```

This is the Ajax function on the client side:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#downloadfile').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'downloadfile',
            success: function(response){
                download(response,'workspace.gz', 'application/gzip');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function download(content, filename, contentType)
{
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob([content], {'type':contentType});
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
}
```

A sample gzipped folder that is 36.5 KB will be inflated to 66.1 KB when downloaded and it clearly can't be extracted.

What I know:

- The file is healthy and extractable on server side.
- The data is transferred and downloaded on the client but inflated and broken.
- The `respone` variable in the JavaScript function looks like binary data (no header whatsoever)

What I don't know:

- Why is the data size increased even though I'm reading and sending the compressed file as binary and both content types are set to `'application/gzip'`?
- If something is added to the file, what is it and when is it being added?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few hours on this, the following worked for me.

The trick was to use the `hexify` on the Django view part. The sending part in the Django view should be :

```py
try:
    with open(tar_path.as_posix(), 'rb') as f:
        file_data = binascii.hexlify(f.read())
    response = HttpResponse(str(file_data), content_type='application/gzip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % userid
    os.remove(tar_path.as_posix())
except IOError:
    response = HttpResponse('File not exist')

return response
```

and the JS part should create a bytearray:

```js
var r = response.substring(2, response.length - 1);
var typedArray = new Uint8Array(r.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {
    return parseInt(h, 16)
}));
download(typedArray, 'workspace.tar.gz', 'application/gzip');
```